# GOPATH not found error from the Gofmt plugin within SublimeText

Tags: go, sublimetext3, gofmt

I keep getting this error within Sublime Text, after installing the `gofmt` package:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abrahma/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Gofmt.sublime-package/gofmt.py", line 257, in run_formatter
    formatter = Formatter(view)
  File "/Users/abrahma/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Gofmt.sublime-package/gofmt.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.cmds = [Command(cmd, self.view, self.window) for cmd in cmds]
  File "/Users/abrahma/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Gofmt.sublime-package/gofmt.py", line 166, in <listcomp>
    self.cmds = [Command(cmd, self.view, self.window) for cmd in cmds]
  File "/Users/abrahma/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages/Gofmt.sublime-package/gofmt.py", line 77, in __init__
    self.window)
  File "/Users/abrahma/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/golangconfig/all/golangconfig.py", line 227, in subprocess_info
    raise exception
golangconfig.EnvVarError: The following environment variable is currently unset: GOPATH
```

My `` file has the following:

```
    "env" : {
        "GOPATH" : "/Users/abrahma/git/go",
        "GOROOT" : "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.7/libexec",
    }
```

(which matches the output of `go env` on my terminal)

I also have a `golang.sublime-settings` file with the following:

```
{
    "env" : {
        "GOPATH" : "/Users/abrahma/git/go",
        "GOROOT" : "/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.12.7/libexec",
    }
}
```

So, for some reason, the `GOPATH` above clearly isn't getting picked up, any ideas why?

Comment: is GOPATH set in your `.profile` file?

Comment: I do have it set in my `.zshrc`

Comment: (and that made me realize ... I needed it in my `.zprofile` -- done, works!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion by @lbu, I realized that I needed this to exist in my *login* shell (`~/.zprofile` in my case), and it works fine now.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.zprofile... Do i need to create it and add `export GOPATH=$(go env GOPATH)`?

Comment: Lol, had this error again, in a new place, and ... found my old question. Sheesh, I didn't _really_ learn after all :-)

Comment: @Pylinux sorry I never answered your question (two years ago!) but ...yes.

Answer (score 15):

Instructions for setting the variables on different OS are mentioned in this doc
https://github.com/golang/sublime-config/blob/master/docs/user.md

I use Sublime3 with GolangConfig in macOs and ran into the same error.
Setting the below in `golang.sublime-settings` helped me fix the issue.

```
{
    "PATH": "/Users/suryapandian/go/bin",
    "GOPATH": "/Users/suryapandian/go"
}
```

Note: Attaching pic below to locate `golang.sublime-settings`

[image]

Comment: this fixed it for me! what a helpful and thorough answer, thank you!

Comment: thank you. glad i could be of help